# two divs side by side- one on far left, the other in middle

Tags: css, html, css-float, padding, margin

I'm creating a WP theme that will have two sections midway down the page. On the left will be "Recent Work," and on the right will be "Recent Blog Posts." I'd like "Recent Blog Posts" to begin in the middle of the page; it's left edge to line up with the container's horizontal mid point. I'd also like for there to be a vertical line separating the two. 
I've played with margins and padding, but can't seem to get the effect I'm going for. Here's an image of what I'm going for:
[image: ideal]

```
<div id="recent">
    <div id="recent-work">
            <p><span>Recent Work</span></p>

    <div class="next">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/next.png" alt="Click for more information" /></a>
    </div><!-- end next -->
    </div><!-- end recent-work -->
    <div id="recent-blog">
        <p><span>Recent Blog</span></p>

    <div class="next">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/next.png" alt="Click for more information" /></a>
    </div><!-- end next -->
    </div><!-- end recent-blog -->
</div><!-- end recent -->
```

and

```
#recent {
    border-top: 1px solid #202020;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#recent #recent-work {
    float: left;
}

#recent #recent-work .next{
    float: right;
}

#recent #recent-work p span {
    font-family: nevis-webfont;
    font-size: 112.5%;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#recent #recent-blog {
    float: right;
}

#recent #recent-blog .next{
    float: right;
}

#recent #recent-blog p span {
    font-family: nevis-webfont;
    font-size: 112.5%;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I've struggled with this since yesterday, so any and all help is greatly appreciated.

@Praveen
[image: changes]

Comment: what is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: @Cristoph I can't figure out how to make the two divs look exactly as they are in my image. Currently, `#recent-work` is on the far left and `#recent-blog` is on the far right. I'd like to have `#recent-blog`'s left edge align with the vertical center of the container.

Comment: @AMC You had given a float left. I reset that! Check out the fiddle. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS, please add this line:

```
#recent #recent-work p {text-align: center;}
```

**Update:**

I added this:

```
#recent #recent-work p, #recent #recent-blog p {text-align: center;}
```

​

Comment: I did this for both `#recent-work` and `#recent-blog`, neither showed any changes..?

Comment: Can you show the live version, so that I can test it out and get the right solution? Even if it is an IP Address of your machine, it is fine. I hope I will be able to access.

Comment: I don't have the site live yet, but maybe this will help..

index.html - http://pastebin.com/qej2G0V8
style.css - http://pastebin.com/Lhcg89ct

Comment: I'll add an image in my original post of what I see now that I've made your recommended changes.

Comment: @AMC You had given a float left. I reset that! Check out the fiddle. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

hope i've got this right -

Working Example - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cedLK/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="leftCont">
    <div class="leftEle"></div>
    <div class="leftEle"></div>
    <div class="leftEle"></div>
</div>
<div class="rightCont">
    <div class="rightEle"></div>
    <div class="rightEle"></div>
    <div class="rightEle"></div>
</div>
</div>​
```

CSS -

```
.rightCont , .leftCont{
width:50%;
float:left;
background-color:green;
min-width:340px;
}
.wrap{
padding-top:20px;
width:100%;
min-width:600px;
height:150px;
overflow:hidden;
background-color:black;
}
.leftEle , .rightEle{
width:30%;
border:2px solid black;
min-width:100px;
float:left;
background-color:yellow;
height:100px;
}
```

​